# Can I play downloaded (classic) games after my PSPlus subscription expires?

Tags: ps3, psn, playstation-plus, god-of-war

I want to get a couple of PS2 classics on my PS3 but they require PS+.

If I buy Playstation Plus and buy these "exclusive PS+ only games" after my subscription is over will it let me play the games I bought?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, You will still be able to play games that you have purchased after your PS+ subscription has expired. Even if they are PS+ exclusives.

Only games that you obtain for free from PS+ are no longer playable after your subscription expires.